# Page never loads

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. When I run it and try to access it using a web browser, the browser never loads the page; it is left stuck in the loading state.

I've tried pausing the debugger, but it doesn't show any threads stopped in the application code:
[image: Call stack showing one thread "In a sleep, wait, or join" and the other in in "External Code"]

It was working fine when the application was first created from the Visual Studio template. I'm not sure which aspects of the application are relevant to this. It's running Elmah for error logging, and it's running under the Visual Studio development web server.

I've tried accessing it using both Internet Explorer and Chrome, and they both have the same problem, so I don't think it's a browser-related problem.

Comment: Maybe you've place a try/catch somewhere and its stopping the erro from showing up.  If you could show some code in your controller/view it would help us help you.

Comment: @AliK, I don't think there's any code in there that's swallowing errors. Also, shouldn't an error terminate the request or trigger an HTTP 5xx error rather than cause a response to never be sent?

Comment: You are right but sometimes it just does not work for some reason.  So what if you create a new MVC app again just for testing does that run?

Comment: Maybe you bave breakpoints?

Answer (score 2):

This stopped happening after doing more code changes and switching to IIS Express. It seems that one of the MVC views was producing an error, but for some reason the debugger wasn't picking it up and the framework wasn't producing an HTTP response.